# NextJS access cookie response in React components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies, next.js

I'm using Next js along with Express backend, for authentication I,m using Cookie, and for protected routes, I have used Next js middleware which is fine, but now I want to access the cookie response in React components to check if we have a cookie then I want to hide register and login links from the navbar, please anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `js-cookie` package to access cookies on the frontend.

Do an import in the react component first:

```js
import Cookies from 'js-cookie'
```

Then access the cookie, maybe do it in useEffect to avoid any issues:

```js
useEffect(()=>{
  const allCookies = Cookies.get();
  console.log(allCookies);
}, []);
```

Comment: ok, Let me try js-cookie

Comment: It gives me an empty object when I do ```const  cookies = Cookie.get()```

Comment: @shakilkhan are you sure your browser has cookies? Check in the developer tools.

Comment: Yes I have checked browser has a cookie with the name of a token

Comment: Through js-cookie we can read httpOnly cookies?

Comment: I don't think that should be the case.

Answer (score 0):

For client-side checking, you can use **`cookieCutter`**

```
import cookieCutter from 'cookie-cutter'
cookieCutter.get('myCookieName')
```